# Transition is not affecting a child element on hover

Tags: html, css

I made an `<a>` which on hover the arrow beside it should move 20px to the right with a transition of 1s. Unfortunately, transition is failing to target the arrow. I don't why is that. Please help me guys.

```
HTML

<a>Register now<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></a>

CSS

a{
  transition: padding-left 1s;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover i{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `transition: padding-left 1s;` to the `i`, not the `a` itself as follows:

```css
a{
  transition: padding-left 1s;
}

a i {
  transition: padding-left 1s;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover i{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a>Register now<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"><span style="width:10px;height:10px;background:black;display:inline-block"/></i></a>
```

*edit: added a span inside the  for demonstration since you don't provide the `fa-solid fa-chevron-right` stylings.